# Time difference under 1h for group of records

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

Table looks like this

```
    Play_name       Status  Date
  1 Romeo & juliet  Start   23.01.2018 16:30:00
  2 Romeo & juliet  Break   23.01.2018 17:15:00
  3 Romeo & juliet  END     23.01.2018 18:30:00
  4 Hamlet          Start   25.01.2018 15:45:00
  5 Hamlet          END     25.01.2018 16:40:00
```

etc

I need to return **play_name** with column **under_hour** with yes for all the plays that lasted shorter than 1h ( from Start to End ).

Results should look like that:

```
   Play_name        under_hour
 1 Romeo & Juliet   NO
 2 Hamlet           Yes
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Where is the END for Hamlet? Also your data isn't properly normalized. Each play name must have a unique ID, which you should've used in this table instead of the name.

Comment: from the documentation:LAG
  { ( value_expr [, offset [, default]]) [ { RESPECT | IGNORE } NULLS ] 
  | ( value_expr [ { RESPECT | IGNORE } NULLS ] [, offset [, default]] )
  }
  OVER ([ query_partition_clause ] order_by_clause)

LEAD
  { ( value_expr [, offset [, default]] ) [ { RESPECT | IGNORE } NULLS ] 
  | ( value_expr [ { RESPECT | IGNORE } NULLS ] [, offset [, default]] )
  }
  OVER ([ query_partition_clause ] order_by_clause)

Comment: @RacilHilan It's just to give overall idea of the issue

Comment: Yes, but it gives the wrong idea. You should at least include the play ID column. As you can see, the answers you got are grouping by the play name, which is a very bad idea, but you didn't leave them any choice.

Comment: How should the Break be used in all of this? For example what if the Break for Romeo and Juliet was over 60 minutes? If that were the case then Romeo and Juliet was also under an hour. I think we need more information before giving an answer. If the break is not being considered in the calculation then no problem but if it needs to be taken into account then the duration of the break in each case will need to be known. It also changes the code required.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks for the feedback, I'll be posting full case scenario next time. Meanwhile you can check the answer to the problem posted by Barbaros Özhan. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAG` function may be used with contribution of `SIGN` and `DECODE` :

```
select rownum rn, Play_name, 
       decode(sign(Finish_Time - Start_Time - (1/24)),-1,'Yes','NO') under_hour
  from
  (
   select Play_name, 
          lag(play_Date,1,null) over (partition by play_name order by play_Date) Start_Time, 
          Play_Date Finish_Time, Status
     from Plays
    where Status in ('Start','END')
    order by Play_Date
   ) 
where Status = 'END';
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b83f4/1)

Comment: Great Answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Doniu Thank you too very much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    Play_name,
    CASE WHEN  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'END' THEN Date END) - MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Start' THEN Date END)) < 1
         THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'YES'
    END AS under_hour
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY Play_name
```

Comment: You picked up on the exact output the OP wants +1.

Answer (score 1):

We can try aggregating by play name and using a pivot to bring the start and end time into a single record.  Then, assert that the difference between these two timestamps is strictly less than one hour.

```
SELECT
    Play_name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Play_name
HAVING
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'END' THEN Date END) -
        MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Start' THEN Date END)) < 1
```

Edit: It seems that you want all plays reported, with a yes/no status.  In this case, you can use the logic in my `HAVING` clause in a `CASE` statement.  Or, just go with the answer by @Jay above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't to check the `Status` value, all you need to do is get the time difference between min and max date of the each play_name record.

```
select  Play_name,CASE when (max(Date)-min(date)) > 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end under_hour from table
```